# What is the difference between installing Xampp and MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

So I discovered that when you install Xampp you get mysql and phpmyadmin but if I download them individually what's the difference?

Comment: From Wikipedia: Features
XAMPP is regularly updated to the latest releases of Apache, MariaDB, PHP and Perl. It also comes with a number of other modules including OpenSSL, phpMyAdmin, MediaWiki, Joomla, WordPress and more.[9] Self-contained, multiple instances of XAMPP can exist on a single computer, and any given instance can be copied from one computer to another. XAMPP is offered in both a full and a standard version (Smaller version). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP#Features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that with xampp you can run apache, filezilla, tomcat and mercury, that are so helpful in some application

Answer (score 2):

When you install xampp you get:

(X) -> Cross-Platform which means it works equally well on Linux, Mac and Windows. 
(A) -> Apache
(M) -> MariaDB 
(P) -> PHP
(P) -> Perl

and when you install only mySql you only get the ->(M) that is the open-source relational database management system.

Honestly depends on **what you need**, if you only need the database install Mysql but if you need to serve web pages, provides support for creating and manipulating databases, setup a local wordPress site... install Xampp

Comment: a much better answer than the accepted one